# save unique key firebase to child

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, unique-key

I have a database like this

```
"Chats" : {
"-MCzU6r-JqvAkC9unjru" : {
  "isSeen" : false,
  "message" : "H",
  "receiver" : "wwRWdMQ62bNwO09M5LpxXks37442",
  "sender" : "R5ICmEp5B6Sbhow523BmQoF6uUG2",
  "timestamp" : "1595571732585",
  "type" : "text"
}}
```

I want to save a unique key  "-MCzU6r-JqvAkC9unjru" in my child, like this

```
"Chats" : {
"-MCzU6r-JqvAkC9unjru" : {
  "isSeen" : false,
  "message" : "H",
  "receiver" : "wwRWdMQ62bNwO09M5LpxXks37442",
  "sender" : "R5ICmEp5B6Sbhow523BmQoF6uUG2",
  "timestamp" : "1595571732585",
  "type" : "text",
  "key" : "-MCzU6r-JqvAkC9unjru"
}}
```

can I do that? if can how I can implement it in my code?

here code for add data to firebase

```
private void sendMessage(final String message) {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    String timestamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("sender", myUid); 
    hashMap.put("receiver", hisUid);
    hashMap.put("message", message);
    hashMap.put("timestamp", timestamp);
    hashMap.put("isSeen", false);
    hashMap.put("type", "text");
    databaseReference.child("Chats").push().setValue(hashMap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
    String key = databaseReference.child("Chats").push().getKey();

    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("sender", myUid); 
    hashMap.put("receiver", hisUid);
    hashMap.put("message", message);
    hashMap.put("timestamp", timestamp);
    hashMap.put("isSeen", false);
    hashMap.put("type", "text");
    hashMap.put("key",key);
    databaseReference.child("Chats").child(key).setValue(hashMap);
```

Using `getKey()` you can retrieve the random id created using `push()` and then add it to the `hashMap`